# Rails sort tags by most used (tag.posts.count)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to show a list of all post tags ordering them by most used.

My controller currently has:

```
@tag_list = Tag.all
```

My view has:

```
<% @tag_list.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.name %>(<%= tag.posts.count %>)
<% end %>
```

EDIT the relationships are as follows:

```
Tag (has_many :posts, :through => :taggings) 
Tagging(belongs_to :tag and belongs_to :post)
Post(has_many :tags, :through => :taggings)
```

This shows all the tags with their count. I have tried playing around with the controller using Tag.order(..) but can't seem to come good.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell rails to automatically maintain a count of posts that use a tag by adding the counter_cache option to the association.

On your Tag model:

```
has_many :posts, :counter_cache => true
```

On your Posts model:

```
belongs_to :tag, :counter_cache => true
```

Via a migration:

```
add_column :tags, :posts_count, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0
```

Any time you add a post with that tag, the tag counter will increment by one. You can then perform your order by easily:

```
Tags.order('posts_count')
```

More information on ActiveRecord Association methods and options can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: I don't think will will work if Post and Tag are in a `has_and_belongs_to` relationship ... which they probably are in reality, right?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...I'm using the relationship Tag (has_many :posts, :through => :taggings), Tagging(belongs_to :tag and belongs_to :post) , Post(has_many :tags, :through => :taggings)

Comment: @Andy: Yeah, I'm pretty sure a has_and_belongs_to_many that relationship won't work with counter_cache. Instead, you'd either need to maintain the count manually via an Observer and adding functionality to the after_create/after_destroy parts of the models' lifecycle or establishing has_many :through relationships.

Comment: @Goldy: With those relationships, you should be fine. :)

Comment: @Goldy: Sure thing. Remember to accept the answer if it's the one that ends up working for you. ;)

Comment: @Shaun will do :) think I'm almost there...getting this error when i add :counter_cache => true to the posts model - "Unknown key(s): counter_cache"...any ideas?