# How to sort tags by "post.count" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I've been developing a blog in Rails and I'm having some issues with a small feature.

I would really like to be able to sort the tags on the page by the number of posts they have attached to them. I used a tagging system like the one found at this [jumpstart](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging) tutorial. Maybe it's not the way I should have gone.

I'm not sure how I would write the Sequel in the controller to order it. Or, if this tagging method wouldn't even be a good way to go.

The relationship is:

```
#tag.rb
has_many :taggings
has_many :posts, through: :taggings

#post.rb
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings

#tagging.rb
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :post
```

I can call in the `count` easily enough once I have tag selected.

```
tag = Tag.first
tag.posts.count

#outputs post count on tag
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache will get you most of the way there

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with my logic. I was trying to count to the posts from tag when I should have been trying to count the taggings.

"[Rails sort tags by most used (tag.posts.count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701961/rails-sort-tags-by-most-used-tag-posts-count)" helped.