# Sort a list of Items in Rails based on Likes done by Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view

I'm new to ruby on rails so please forgive the question. I tried following this example [Rails sort tags by most used (tag.posts.count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701961/rails-sort-tags-by-most-used-tag-posts-count][1]) but kept getting an error "undefined method `order' for Items:Module". I am trying to sort a list of items based on an item's likes. So an item with 5 likes should be placed above an item with only 3 likes. I have listed below all my relevant code down below. Thank you so much guys!!

**Like.rb**

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :item, :counter_cache => true
belongs_to :user
end
```

**Likes_controller.rb**

```
class Items::LikesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_book

def create      
    @item.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create             
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @item}
        format.js
    end
end 
def destroy
    @item.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @item}
        format.js
    end
end
private 
def set_book
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
end
end
```

**Item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
has_many :likes, :counter_cache => true
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@items = Item.all   
Items.order('likes_count')
end

def show
@items = Item.find(params[:id])
end


private

def set_user
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
   <% @items.each do |item| %>
<%=  item.product %>
<div><%= image_tag(item.avatar.url(:thumb)) %></div>
<% end %>
```

Migrations Relevant

```
class AddLikecountsToItem < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
add_column :items, :likes_count, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0
 end
end

class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :likes do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :item_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

end
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @items = Item.order('likes_count')
end
```

Comment: Zaur thank you for your answer. Although that gets the screen to appear, no ordering by "like" has been achieved. Its still showing ordering by time created. Some items that have 5 likes are below things that have none but were created earlier.

Comment: I also added my migrations so you can see how they were created. Thank you so much for your help sir

Comment: Do you see the correct likes counts in database? You may need to reset counters using the following code:

Item.each { |item| Item.reset_counters(item.id, :likes) }

Comment: Do i put this in my index.html.erb? thanks again Zaur

Comment: Also you only need to specify the :counter_cache option on the belongs_to side of the association.

Comment: no, run the code above in rails console. you only need to run this once to fix initial values. the future updates will be automatic.

Comment: Zaur, I get this following message in my rails c when i run your command:
irb(main):003:0> Item.each { |item| Item.reset_counters(item.id, :likes) } 
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Class:0x007fd5ed4515f8>

Comment: sorry, try: Item.all.each { |item| Item.reset_counters(item.id, :likes) }

Comment: When I do
Item.all => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Item id: 1, product: "Bond Cologne", amount: 565, created_at: "2016-12-10 20:56:16", updated_at: "2016-12-10 20:56:16",  user_id: nil, likes_count: 0>, #<Item id: 2, product: "Mac Laptop", amount: 2000, created_at: "2016-12-10 21:10:43", updated_at: "2016-12-10 21:10:43",  user_id: nil, likes_count: 0>, #<Item id: 3, product: "Total War Atilla", amount: 50, created_at: "2016-12-10 21:13:06", updated_at: "2016-12-10 21:13:06", user_id: nil, likes_count: 1>]>

Comment: Give me 10 seconds

Comment: Awesome, its almost there > its just that its putting zero likes on top and highest likes in the buttom is there any way to make the highest in the top?

Comment: @items = Item.order('likes_count DESC')

Comment: You are amazing Zaur!! Thank you so much!!